# Linear Approximation with log

Tags: calculus, approximation

The problem:

Find the linear approximation of the function
$$
f(x,y) = \ln(e+x+y)
$$
at point $(0, 0)$. Use it to approximate the value of the function at $(0.1, 0.2)$

---

What I have so far:

I found the gradient of $f$ to be
$$
\nabla f = \left\langle \frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{y} \right\rangle.
$$

However, I end up dividing by $0$ when plugging the point $(0, 0)$ into the gradient.

What property am I missing? Or have I taken a wrong direction altogether?

Comment: You miscomputed the gradient.

Comment: How so? 1 + ln(x) + ln(y), and partial derivatives gives 1/x and 1/y

Comment: $\log$ is not linear, so definitely $\log(e+x+y)\neq \log e+\log x+\log y$ (you have $\log (exy)=\log e +\log x+\log y$)

Comment: I think I understand you. Does this function have to be rewrited/simplified in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,
$$
\nabla f = \left\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right\rangle = \left\langle \frac{1}{e + x + y}, \frac{1}{e + x + y} \right\rangle.
$$

Evaluating both the function and its gradient at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ gives
$$
f(0, 0) = 0, \qquad \nabla f(0, 0) = \bigl\langle \tfrac{1}{e}, \tfrac{1}{e} \bigr\rangle,
$$
so for nearby $(x, y)$, the linear approximation $L$ is given by
$$
\begin{align}
L(x, y) &= f(0, 0) + \nabla f(0, 0) \cdot \langle x - 0, y - 0 \rangle \\
&= 0 + \bigl\langle \tfrac{1}{e}, \tfrac{1}{e} \bigr\rangle \cdot \langle x, y \rangle \\
&= \frac{x}{e} + \frac{y}{e} \\
&= \frac{x + y}{e}.
\end{align}
$$

So,
$$
L(0.1, 0.2) = \frac{0.3}{e} \approx 0.1104.
$$